# Angular testing manually create HttpEvent from HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-test

I've created a custom HttpInterceptor that I'm now trying to write tests for. In order to do this I'm mocking an HttpHandler.

I want the handle method of my mock handler to emit whatever I tell it to, so I'm trying to create a mock handler to spit out an HttpErrorResponse like so:

```
const handle = jest.fn(() => of(new HttpErrorResponse({})));
interceptor.intercept(req, {handle});
```

But I'm getting the typescript error below:

[image]

How do I fix this? It's quite possible that I'm going about testing this all wrong, as well, so I'm open to suggestions!

**EDIT:**

The crux of the issue seems to be that I can't (don't know how to) manually create an HttpEvent!.

Comment: Can't you just do this `const error = new HttpErrorResponse({})`?

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek - I'm going to make an edit to perhaps better Illustrated my problem, hang tight!

Comment: what do you want to test in your interceptor? I see a "should not dispatch..." Usually you test if the interceptor did what it had to do on an intercepted request or response. So you need to create an actual request (mock one) You force a status 500 in your stub

Comment: @gyc - I'm actually building an ngrx request/response interceptor that dispatches actions based on certain requests. Additionally, I figured out that I was doing all this wrong and should just be using HttpClientTestingModule rather than manually created requests/responses.

Answer (score 2):

I was doing this all wrong. Don't manually create HttpEvent's/Requests/Responses and just use `HttpClientTestingModule` and it's goodness.